# Can we use single JedisConnectionFactory instance with multiple spring redis template?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-boot, jedis, spring-data-redis

I have multiple Spring Redis Template with diffrent serializers. Can I use same JedisConnectionFactory instance for both?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the same `JedisConnectionFactory` with multiple Spring Redis templates by specifiying the `connectionFactory` property in the bean definition for your Redis template(s).

Example:

```
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="port" value="6379"/>
    <property name="usePool" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="redisTemplateOne" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="keySerializer">
        <bean class="com.example.KeyOne"/>
    </property>
    <property name="valueSerializer">
        <bean class="com.example.ValueOne"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="redisTemplateTwo" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="keySerializer">
        <bean class="com.example.KeyTwo"/>
    </property>
    <property name="valueSerializer">
        <bean class="com.example.ValueTwo"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I found the answer way back by hit and trial.
Please update your answer using java config also. I will mark it as accepted then.